# Apply event listener to an editable polygon

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

How to add a event listener to a google maps editable Polygon when the user changes its boundary?

I tried the code below. [Here is a Fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/eq1h9LLa/19/)

```
google.maps.event.addListener(PolygonPath, 'drag', function(e) {

        window.alert("Hi");

});
```

This is what I want: 
[image: Example]

**code snippet (from linked fiddle):**

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#map {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>

<script>
  var PolygonPath;

  function initMap() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 8,
      center: {
        lat: 0,
        lng: 0
      }
    });

    PolygonPath = new google.maps.Polygon({
      strokeColor: '#FF8C00',
      strokeOpacity: 1.0,
      strokeWeight: 3,
      editable: true,
      //geodesic: true,
      map: map
    });


    console.log(PolygonPath);


    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(e) {
      addLatLng(e);
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(PolygonPath, 'drag', function(e) {

      window.alert("Hi");

    });

  }


  function addLatLng(event) {
    pathLine = PolygonPath.getPath();
    pathLine.push(event.latLng);
    //ValueUnit = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeArea(pathLine);

  }
</script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
```

Comment: related question: [Event handler for editing a Google Maps Polyline?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15693077/event-handler-for-editing-a-google-maps-polyline)

Comment: related question: [calculate area of a drawn polygon on google map javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12671077/calculate-area-of-a-drawn-polygon-on-google-map-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the event listener to the Polygon's path:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(PolygonPath.getPath(), 'insert_at', function(evt) {
  document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = PolygonPath.getPath().getAt(evt).toUrlValue(6);
});
```

There are three interesting events on an [MVCArray](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MVCArray) (as they apply to a Polygon path):

- insert_at - add a vertex
- remove_at - delete a vertex
- set_at - change a vertex

**code snippet implementing insert_at and set_at listeners on the Polygon path:**

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#map {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="info"></div>
<div id="map"></div>

<script>
  var PolygonPath;

  function initMap() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 8,
      center: {
        lat: 0,
        lng: 0
      }
    });

    PolygonPath = new google.maps.Polygon({
      strokeColor: '#FF8C00',
      strokeOpacity: 1.0,
      strokeWeight: 3,
      editable: true,
      //geodesic: true,
      map: map
    });


    console.log(PolygonPath);

    google.maps.event.addListener(PolygonPath.getPath(), 'insert_at', function(evt) {
      document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = "insert:" + PolygonPath.getPath().getAt(evt).toUrlValue(6);
    })
    google.maps.event.addListener(PolygonPath.getPath(), 'set_at', function(evt) {
      document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = "set:" + PolygonPath.getPath().getAt(evt).toUrlValue(6);
    })
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(e) {
      addLatLng(e);
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(PolygonPath, 'drag', function(e) {

      window.alert("Hi");

    });

  }


  function addLatLng(event) {
    pathLine = PolygonPath.getPath();
    pathLine.push(event.latLng);
    //ValueUnit = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeArea(pathLine);

  }
</script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
```