# Javascript Google maps drawing events

Tags: javascript, google-maps, dom-events

I'm having a problem with the event listeners provided by Google maps API. The thing is, that some events run, some not. I have a setListeners function which sets the listeners after the polygon overlay is complete. The events I would like to hook are: set_at, insert_at, remove_at and click. Now the click events run correctly, but the others not. What could I do wrong? Here is the code:

```
self.setListeners = function () {
        //this click event runs correctly
        google.maps.event.addListener(self.map, 'click', function (e) {
            self.clearSelection();
        })

        console.log(self.drost);
        if (typeof self.drost != 'undefined') {
            self.drost.addListener('set_at', function (e) {
                console.log(e.overlay);
            });
            self.drost.addListener('insert_at', function (e) {
                console.log(e.overlay);
            });
            self.drost.addListener('remove_at', function (e) {
                console.log(e.overlay);
            });
            //this click also runs correctly
            self.drost.addListener('click', function(e){
                self.setSelection(self.drost);
            })
        }
}
```

Comment: is self.drost defined?  Assuming 'drost' is the polygon, have you tried adding the listener on the google maps event `overlaycomplete`? https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/drawinglayer

Comment: @JorgeObregon Yes, the self.drost is initialized in the overlaycomplete event from e.overlay. Also, I call the setListeners at the end of the overlaycomplete callback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The events `set_at`, `insert_at`, `remove_at` need to be added to the **path** of the polygon, not the polygon itself.

related questions:

- [Apply event listener to an editable polygon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38529443/apply-event-listener-to-an-editable-polygon)
- [calculate area of a drawn polygon on google map javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12671077/calculate-area-of-a-drawn-polygon-on-google-map-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the listener with google.maps.event:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(self.drost, 'set_at', function() {
   console.log('it works!');
});
```

Comment: btw, this answer could be a comment as well, but a snippet of code will help you more than just a link to google documentation

Comment: I tried this method, this also does not work. If I  add a console log right after the if, like console.log(self.drost) it logs a google maps polygon object. But the event listener callback does not run when I fire an event. But +1 for the effort! :)